# Pandas - extract method not matching anything

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am having a problem with this seemingly easy task to do.
Here 's a recreation of my problem:

I have a dataframe called legal of this form:

```
+----+-----------------+
|    | legal           |
|----+-----------------|
|  0 | gmbh            |
|  1 | kg              |
|  2 | ag              |
|  3 | GmbH & Co. KGaA |
|  4 | LP              |
|  5 | LLP             |
|  6 | LLLP            |
|  7 | LLC             |
|  8 | PLLC            |
|  9 | corp            |
| 10 | corporation     |
| 11 | inc             |
| 12 | cic             |
| 13 | cio             |
| 14 | ltd             |
| 15 | s.a.            |
+----+-----------------+
```

It contains all the words that can represent a legal term of a given company.

Now I have another dataframe containing a list of company raw names that might also contain some legal terms.
My task is to identify such legal terms for each company row name in the `companies` dataframe.
I am trying to use some regex so that the legal terms might both be uppercase and lowercase (or a mix). So I am using the method **extract** for that.

For the sake of the demonstration, my first company raw name is `2&0 Technologies Inc`, so for that company I would expect to extract the world `inc` from my legal dataframe.

This is the simplified version of my code with some comments:

```
def format_companies(self, legals, locations):
        self.companies['base_name'] = ''
        self.companies['location'] = ''
        self.companies['legal'] = ''
        for i, row in self.companies.iterrows():
            legal_pattern = '/(' + "|".join(row['raw'].split()]) +')/ig'
            legal_pattern = rf'{legal_pattern}'
            print(legal_pattern) # It prints out -> /(2&0|Technologies|Inc)/ig
            legal = legals['legal'].str.extract(legal_pattern)
            print(tabulate(legal, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql')) # Everything is NaN. (results will be print below)
            if i >= 0:
                break
```

The first print statement is just to print out the pattern used in the extract method, which is `/(2&0|Technologies|Inc)/ig`.

The second pattern is to print out the results from the extract method, and as said in the comments, it returns a list of NaNs:

```
+----+-----+
|    |   0 |
|----+-----|
|  0 | nan |
|  1 | nan |
|  2 | nan |
|  3 | nan |
|  4 | nan |
|  5 | nan |
|  6 | nan |
|  7 | nan |
|  8 | nan |
|  9 | nan |
| 10 | nan |
| 11 | nan |
| 12 | nan |
| 13 | nan |
| 14 | nan |
| 15 | nan |
+----+-----+
```

I am very confused because if you try out the regular expression `/(2&0|Technologies|Inc)/ig` on the text 'inc' on https://www.regextester.com/, inc gets selected correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.extract()` does not recognize regex pattern with `/i` to indicate IGNORECASE. To solve this, you can do it in 2 ways:

**Method 1:** Change your definition of `legal_pattern` without the `/` and `/ig`:

```
legal_pattern = '(' + "|".join(row['raw'].split()]) +')'
legal_pattern = rf'{legal_pattern}'
```

Instead, use the flag `re.IGNORECASE` in `str.extract()`, as follows:

```
import re
legals['legal'].str.extract(legal_pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
```

**Method 2:** Alternatively, you can also use `(?i)` in the regex to indicate IGNORECASE, as follows:

```
legal_pattern = '(?i)(' + "|".join(row['raw'].split()]) +')'
legal_pattern = rf'{legal_pattern}'
```

Then, you can use `str.extract()` without specifying `re.IGNORECASE`:

```
legals['legal'].str.extract(legal_pattern)
```

**Result:**

```
      0
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   NaN
10  NaN
11  inc
12  NaN
13  NaN
14  NaN
15  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, they both work fine. I didn't know that you couldn't use /i when utilizing the extract method.